# Facebook app - client token more than 60 days

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have an applicatoin that gets the birthday of the users threw a form and than it's supposed to write on there wall on there birthday.

Is this possible? even if they visit the app today and there birthday is in 200 days? Because I know the token only lasts 60 days and I want to post with there fb profile.

If I try to post the message on my fan page (where I can get a token that lasts forever) and tag them it doesn't work, because facebook doesn't allow tagging threw the api, you have any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Comment: Posting message content on a user’s wall that they did not actively create themselves (a.k.a.: _typed_ it in somewhere) is against Platform Policies anyway … please don’t build another one of those useless spam apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posting a feed on the user's wall, you can use the **APP Access Token** instead of the extended user token you are saving.

[App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens)

Comment: So if the user never comes back to my fb app, can I post on his wall even after 300 days?

Comment: Of course. Only coindition is that the user must have granted the publish permission. You can try this yourself

Comment: I have to try this it, because you and reach4thelasers have totally 180 degrese opinions haha.

Comment: What have you tried? Isnt it working? Of course this shaal work, I;ve been using this in many of my apps

Answer (score 0):

Facebook removed the offline_access permission a couple of years back:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

"Note: The user must access your application before you're able to get a valid "authorization Code" to be able to make the server-side OAuth call again. Apps will not be able to setup a background/cron job that tries to automatically extend the expiration time, because the "authorization code" is short-lived and will have expired."

Basically you need an Authorization code to get a new token, and you can only get that if the user actively uses your app.

Comment: So if the users visits today my app and than never come back, can the app post on his wall after 300 days?

Comment: NO - that's the point, they need to come back or your lose the right to interact with their Facebook account.

Comment: Right, I was thinking same, what you think is the best method to get 60 days token from every user that vists my app and than extend the token when he revisits?

Comment: Yep that's all you can do